# Why does combined count query takes too long to execute?

Tags: mysql

Server won't byte on this query, it takes too long to execute:

```
select prodavac.id, count(artikl.id) as brojartikala, count(poruceno.id) as brojporudzbina from prod_prodavac prodavac 
inner join prod_artikl artikl 
    on prodavac.id=artikl.prodavacid 
inner join prod_poruceno poruceno 
    on prodavac.id=poruceno.prodavacid 
group by prodavac.id
```

On the other hand, both semi-queries run mega fast:

```
select prodavac.id, count(artikl.id) as brojartikala from prod_prodavac prodavac 
inner join prod_artikl artikl 
    on prodavac.id=artikl.prodavacid 
group by prodavac.id
```

Also the other one:

```
select prodavac.id, count(poruceno.id) as brojporudzbina from prod_prodavac prodavac 
inner join prod_poruceno poruceno 
    on prodavac.id=poruceno.prodavacid 
group by prodavac.id 
order by prodavac.id asc
```

I would really like to do it in one query, so how to merge them correct way? All IDs are indexed integers.

Explain select shows this:

[image]

Comment: run `explain select ...` to see the execution plan

Comment: I've added the screen.

Comment: You could try to force the index: `... inner join prod_poruceno poruceno FORCE INDEX FOR JOIN (poruceno)
    on prodavac.id=poruceno.prodavacid ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the relations between the tables and the data, your combined query might not even return the desired result. For a simple count of relations you can use correlated subqueries in the SELECT clause:

```
select prodavac.id, (
    select count(*)
    from prod_artikl artikl 
    where artikl.prodavacid = prodavac.id
  ) as brojartikala, (
    select count(*)
    from prod_poruceno poruceno 
    where poruceno.prodavacid = prodavac.id
  ) as brojporudzbina
from prod_prodavac prodavac
order by prodavac.id asc
```